# How to import remote AMD modules with Angular2+WebPack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

In my Angular2+TypeScript+WebPack project I would like to use / import the Esri ArcGIS JavaScript API from the following url:

https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/

so that a `import Map from 'esri/Map';` would import the following module

https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/esri/Map.js

I've seen people are typically using systemjs to load these modules, however, I would prefer not to use systemjs. Is there a way to do that with webpack only?

webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './app/polyfills.js',
        'vendor': './app/vendor.js',
        'app': './app/boot.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./prod/[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {screw_ie8: true, keep_fnames: true},
            compress: {screw_ie8: true},
            comments: false
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> webpack is a module bundler not a javascript loader. It package files from local disk and don't load files from the web (except its own chunks). Use a javascript loader, i.e. [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js)

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150#issuecomment-32756166

It's also worth noting you won't be able to load a module from an external source and then import using es6 syntax as the remote module needs to go through Webpack. You'll have to make sure you fetch a [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) / global script.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this sample](https://github.com/lobsteropteryx/esri-webpack-typescript) and was able to load dojo, webpack, typescript and angular 2.

Just be patient, is still hellish with imports eg:

```
import * as Map from 'esri/Map';
import * as Point from 'esri/geometry/Point';
import * as Circle from 'esri/geometry/Circle';
```